# How to load a 32bit dll in a 64 bit process

Tags: c#, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I know that you cannot call a 32bit dll directly from a 64bit process. 
But none of the answers on SO seem to offer sample code on how it could/should be done.

Could somebody post a sample code on how

```
processA(64) > processB(32) > DllA(32)
```

How can ProcessA get the value back from a method in DllA via ProcessB

Could someone post some simple code of the DLL, processB and ProcessA

Comment: That really depends on the job. What does the DLL do?

Comment: Does it really matter?
All the 32bit dll does is string processing, I pass a string as an argument and another string is returned. (the strings are XML).

Comment: You can use .NET remoting, or better WCF.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with either .NET remoting or WCF. Do you have any sample code that might help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4195587/613130

Comment: I asked about the job because there are several different IPC methodologies and if you wish to pass an object (eg.) it would require a more elaborated code

Comment: I see, would you then know where I could find some simple code to achieve a simple request from 64 > 32.